# React native VirtualizedList Re-render while scroll the list

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, rerender

I have Virtualized List initial render record up to 30 ,while render the data list automatically re render 2 to 4 times and also the new data added to the list

while rendering multi times we can't able to do any action like touch or navigate to another screen

**My Code**

```
class HomeDetails extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.cellRefs = {};
    this.flatListRef = React.createRef();
  }
getItem = (data, index) => {
    if (index in data) {
      return {
        key: `${data[index].id} - ${index}`,
        id: data[index].id,
        accountId: data[index].accountId,
        displayName: data[index].displayName,
        fullName: data[index].fullName,
  
      };
    }
  };

  keyExtractor(item, index) {
    return `${item.id} - ${index}`;
  }

  getItemCount = data => {
    return data.length;
  };

  _renderItem =({item,index}) => {
    console.log(
      'Rerendring',
      item.accountId,
      moment().format('MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss a'),
    );
    return (
     
        <View key={index} style={{height: 50,  flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <Text>{`${item.accountId}   ${moment().format(
            'MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss a',
          )}`}</Text>
        </View>
   
    );

}

render(){
return (
<VirtualizedList
              onScroll={this.onScrollHandler}
              onViewableItemsChanged={this._onViewableItemsChanged}
              viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
              scrollEventThrottle={16}
              ref={this.flatListRef}
              horizontal={false}
              decelerationRate="normal"
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              data={this.props.responseRecord}
              pagingEnabled={true}
              scrollToOverflowEnabled={false}
              renderItem={this._renderItem}
              keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
              getItemCount={this.getItemCount}
              getItem={this.getItem}
              windowSize={21}
              progressViewOffset={20}
              initialNumToRender={15}
              maxToRenderPerBatch={15}
              updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100}
              onEndReached={val => {
                return this.props.getExtraData(2, 1);
              }}
              onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
              refreshing={this.props.postLoading}
              extraData={this.props.refreshData}
              disableIntervalMomentum={false}
              removeClippedSubviews={true}
              onRefresh={() => {
                return this.props.getExtraData(1, 1);
              }} 
              ItemSeparator={this.ItemSeparator}
              ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
             
            />
)
}
}

const mapStateToProps = ({post, auth, common}) => {
  const {
    responseRecord,
    postLoading,
    refreshData,

  } = post;

  return {
     responseRecord,
    postLoading,
    refreshData,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {

  getExtraData,

};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeDetails);
```

..........................................................................

1.For initial 30 record rendering its re-render more that 2 times
2.when add more records its re-render more than 4 to 6 times
3.tried with purecomponent but no luck

code deployed in snack
https://snack.expo.dev/@pandianvpsm/cd5737

Answer (score 0):

Internal, React's PureComponent implements the `shouldComponentUpdate` method and compares previous props values and new props or state values to avoid unnecessary re-renders.

This works well for primitive type values like `numbers`, `strings`, and `booleans`.

For referential types values (`objects` and `arrays`), this comparison is not always accurate. This is the behavior you have. `this.props.responseRecord` is an array of objects (referential types).

We can solve this problem by implementing our own `componentShouldUpdate` method as below:

```
  /** Trigger component rerender only new elements added */
   shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
      return this.props.responseRecord.length !== nextProps.responseRecord.length
   
  }
```

Full code below

```
class HomeDetails extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.cellRefs = {};
    this.flatListRef = React.createRef();
  }

  /** Trigger component rerender only new elements added */
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.props.responseRecord.length !== nextProps.responseRecord;
  }
  getItem = (data, index) => {
    if (index in data) {
      return {
        key: `${data[index].id} - ${index}`,
        id: data[index].id,
        accountId: data[index].accountId,
        displayName: data[index].displayName,
        fullName: data[index].fullName,
      };
    }
  };

  keyExtractor(item, index) {
    return `${item.id} - ${index}`;
  }

  getItemCount = (data) => {
    return data.length;
  };

  _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    console.log(
      "Rerendring",
      item.accountId,
      moment().format("MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss a")
    );
    return (
      <View key={index} style={{ height: 50, flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <Text>{`${item.accountId}   ${moment().format(
          "MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss a"
        )}`}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <VirtualizedList
        onScroll={this.onScrollHandler}
        onViewableItemsChanged={this._onViewableItemsChanged}
        viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        ref={this.flatListRef}
        horizontal={false}
        decelerationRate="normal"
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={this.props.responseRecord}
        pagingEnabled={true}
        scrollToOverflowEnabled={false}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        getItemCount={this.getItemCount}
        getItem={this.getItem}
        windowSize={21}
        progressViewOffset={20}
        initialNumToRender={15}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={15}
        updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100}
        onEndReached={(val) => {
          return this.props.getExtraData(2, 1);
        }}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
        refreshing={this.props.postLoading}
        extraData={this.props.refreshData}
        disableIntervalMomentum={false}
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        onRefresh={() => {
          return this.props.getExtraData(1, 1);
        }}
        ItemSeparator={this.ItemSeparator}
        ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ post, auth, common }) => {
  const { responseRecord, postLoading, refreshData } = post;

  return {
    responseRecord,
    postLoading,
    refreshData,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getExtraData,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeDetails);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ,but still the continuous rendering occur ,i don't no how to fix the issue, please any one help me